# Table spacing issue converting to PDF via LaTeX with pandoc

Tags: tables, r, knitr, pandoc

In the application of [Rmarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) I often found my answers concerning “LaTeX” and “pandoc” here at [TeX Stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com). For that reason I want to repeat here my [question I asked at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549464/no-automatic-line-break-in-texreg-notes-using-r-markdown) hoping to find a solution to following issue while converting to PDF via LaTeX with pandoc:

I'm facing the issue that in R `texreg()` doesn't seem to break the lines in the notes below the table. Also the margins between the models are not extended equally like it's happening with `htmlreg()` which gives a clean result. Manual breaks like `\n` or HTML tags are not working with 'texreg'. There's a partly [workaround from MichaelChirico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902906/wrapping-custom-notes-in-texreg-output), but one has to change the `texreg()` function but it seems the method doesn't respect the case when we're dealing with more than one model side by side.

Here is the code I'm using:

````markdown
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "jaySf"
date: "13 Juni 2017"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r results="asis"}
library(car)
lm1 <- lm(prestige ~ income, data=Duncan)
lm2 <- lm(prestige ~ education, data=Duncan)
lm3 <- lm(prestige ~ income + education, data=Duncan)

library(texreg)
texreg(list(lm1, lm2, lm3), custom.note = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>consetetur sadipscing 
       elitr, sed diam. %stars.") # for pdf output

htmlreg(list(lm1, lm2, lm3), custom.note = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>consetetur sadipscing 
       elitr, sed diam. %stars.") # for html output
```
````

And this is the output:

[image: ugly table]

Does anybody have a clue? Any help is appreciated.

And here the LaTeX code which is produced:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{%
\usepackage{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{unicode=true,
            pdftitle={Untitled},
            pdfauthor={jaySf},
            pdfborder={0 0 0},
            breaklinks=true}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newcommand{\VerbBar}{|}
\newcommand{\VERB}{\Verb[commandchars=\\\{\}]}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
% Add ',fontsize=\small' for more characters per line
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{248,248,248}
\newenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}}
\newcommand{\KeywordTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\DataTypeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\BaseNTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\FloatTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ConstantTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\SpecialCharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\StringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\VerbatimStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\SpecialStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ImportTok}[1]{{#1}}
\newcommand{\CommentTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textit{{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\DocumentationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
\newcommand{\AnnotationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
\newcommand{\CommentVarTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
\newcommand{\OtherTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\FunctionTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\VariableTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ControlFlowTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\OperatorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.81,0.36,0.00}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\BuiltInTok}[1]{{#1}}
\newcommand{\ExtensionTok}[1]{{#1}}
\newcommand{\PreprocessorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textit{{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\AttributeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.77,0.63,0.00}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\RegionMarkerTok}[1]{{#1}}
\newcommand{\InformationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
\newcommand{\WarningTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
\newcommand{\AlertTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.94,0.16,0.16}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ErrorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.64,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\NormalTok}[1]{{#1}}
\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
\IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
\usepackage{parskip}
}{% else
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
% Redefines (sub)paragraphs to behave more like sections
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
\let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi

%%% Use protect on footnotes to avoid problems with footnotes in titles
\let\rmarkdownfootnote\footnote%
\def\footnote{\protect\rmarkdownfootnote}

%%% Change title format to be more compact
\usepackage{titling}

% Create subtitle command for use in maketitle
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{
  \posttitle{
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    }
}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-2em}
  \title{Untitled}
  \pretitle{\vspace{\droptitle}\centering\huge}
  \posttitle{\par}
  \author{jaySf}
  \preauthor{\centering\large\emph}
  \postauthor{\par}
  \predate{\centering\large\emph}
  \postdate{\par}
  \date{13 Juni 2017}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{library}\NormalTok{(car)}
\NormalTok{lm1 <-}\StringTok{ }\KeywordTok{lm}\NormalTok{(prestige ~}\StringTok{ }\NormalTok{income, }\DataTypeTok{data=}\NormalTok{Duncan)}
\NormalTok{lm2 <-}\StringTok{ }\KeywordTok{lm}\NormalTok{(prestige ~}\StringTok{ }\NormalTok{education, }\DataTypeTok{data=}\NormalTok{Duncan)}
\NormalTok{lm3 <-}\StringTok{ }\KeywordTok{lm}\NormalTok{(prestige ~}\StringTok{ }\NormalTok{income +}\StringTok{ }\NormalTok{education, }\DataTypeTok{data=}\NormalTok{Duncan)}

\KeywordTok{library}\NormalTok{(texreg)}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\begin{verbatim}
## Version:  1.36.23
## Date:     2017-03-03
## Author:   Philip Leifeld (University of Glasgow)
## 
## Please cite the JSS article in your publications -- see citation("texreg").
\end{verbatim}

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{texreg}\NormalTok{(}\KeywordTok{list}\NormalTok{(lm1, lm2, lm3), }\DataTypeTok{custom.note =} \StringTok{"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>consetetur sadipscing }
\StringTok{       elitr, sed diam. %stars."}\NormalTok{)}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c }
\hline
 & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 \\
\hline
(Intercept) & $2.46$       & $0.28$       & $-6.06$      \\
            & $(5.19)$     & $(5.09)$     & $(4.27)$     \\
income      & $1.08^{***}$ &              & $0.60^{***}$ \\
            & $(0.11)$     &              & $(0.12)$     \\
education   &              & $0.90^{***}$ & $0.55^{***}$ \\
            &              & $(0.08)$     & $(0.10)$     \\
\hline
R$^2$       & 0.70         & 0.73         & 0.83         \\
Adj. R$^2$  & 0.69         & 0.72         & 0.82         \\
Num. obs.   & 45           & 45           & 45           \\
RMSE        & 17.40        & 16.69        & 13.37        \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\scriptsize{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>consetetur sadipscing 
       elitr, sed diam. $^{***}p<0.001$, $^{**}p<0.01$, $^*p<0.05$.}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistical models}
\label{table:coefficients}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{htmlreg}\NormalTok{(}\KeywordTok{list}\NormalTok{(lm1, lm2, lm3), }\DataTypeTok{custom.note =} \StringTok{"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>consetetur sadipscing }
\StringTok{       elitr, sed diam. %stars."}\NormalTok{)}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

Statistical models

Model 1

Model 2

Model 3

(Intercept)

2.46

0.28

-6.06

(5.19)

(5.09)

(4.27)

income

1.08***

0.60***

(0.11)

(0.12)

education

0.90***

0.55***

(0.08)

(0.10)

R2

0.70

0.73

0.83

Adj. R2

0.69

0.72

0.82

Num. obs.

45

45

45

RMSE

17.40

16.69

13.37

{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam.
\emph{\textbf{p \textless{} 0.001, }p \textless{} 0.01, }p \textless{}
0.05.}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Somebody might have more of a clue if you posted a minimal working example. That is, code we can compile to reproduce the issue. (A minimal `.tex` basically.)

Comment: Sure! Would the Rmarkdown code be fruitful?

Comment: It would probably be helpful to post the generated LaTeX code, too. That way, you might get partial help from people who know LaTeX but not R and that might help somebody who knows R but not LaTeX to generate a solution.

Comment: Done__________!

Comment: See also the new `threeparttable` argument described in my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902906/wrapping-custom-notes-in-texreg-output/62439440#62439440.

Comment: @PhilipLeifeld Great new feature, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you custom note end in a `\multicolumn`, so you can not use line break comands as `\par` or `\\`, but you can use a `\parbox`:

```
custom.note = "\\parbox{\\linewidth}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
\\\\ consetetur sadipscing    elitr, sed diam. %stars.}"
```

[image: mwe]

You can also allow an automatic line break in a narrow `\parbox`, thus  avoiding the excessive width of the last column:

```
custom.note = "\\parbox{.4\\linewidth}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam. %stars.}"
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Would be a pleasantly short solution. Now how can we 1.) avoid the table to spread across the whole sheet and 2.) civilize texreg (assuming it's responsibility) to evenly distribute the columns (e. g. when setting some kind of table width). The latter can no be achieved by setting `no.margin = TRUE`.

Comment: Try with `custom.note = "\\parbox{.4\\linewidth}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing  elitr, sed diam. %stars.}"`

Comment: You did it. Just great, thanks! I like the justification when extending the text. With `\\\\ `  e.g. before the `%stars` we can insert a custom line break.

Comment: For the use of publication the first line of the note might be a little too close to the table, in comparison to my table above. Could you eventually provide an improvement?

Comment: @jaySf Yes, start the `\parbox` content  with  some vertical space: ` \\smallskip Lore ... ` or `\vspace{3pt} Lore ...`  , for example, or better, increase a little the height of all  table rows; e.g. `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}`.

Comment: I'm not sure where exactly to put `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}` and why is it better?  `\\vspace{3pt}` works great.

Comment: @jaySf Where? Of course, before of the table code (the R chunk , in this case) Why ? because increasing the heights of all rows, look better a   "R² "  without a rule on top and so on. Just compare an array stretch of 1 and 1.3 in `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{|l|}\hline R$^2$\\\hline\end{tabular}
\end{document} `

Comment: Okay, now I got you. Indeed there was no space before the R² I didn't notice because I was so much focused on the custum note. Now (keeping the `\vspace{3pt}`) it  is even better formatted than the original version! This is fantastic! Thanks again.